# Discord.py set status (client)

Tags: python, discord

**Hello,**
How i set status to the bot?

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
```

(I dont want change to bot.event because i have RolePlay bot and with bot.event and bot is spamming messages. Help me how to set status with client.event.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this if you want to use `client`:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))    # Here we change it

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Your code

client.run('your token here')
```

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.